# How to pass user-provided argument to a plot function within my function?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following function:

```
foo = function(x, y){
    plot(x, y)
}
```

When I run `foo(1:10, 11:20)`, how do I get the axis labels to say `1:10` and `11:20` rather than `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's what you want, you can do

```
foo = function(x, y, xlab=deparse(substitute(x)), ylab=deparse(substitute(y))){
  plot(x, y, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
}
foo(1:10, 11:20)
```

This will default to the exact values you pass, but you can override by setting explicitly values.

Alternativly, if you just want to essentially change the call from your function to the plot function and pass everything though, you could do something like

```
foo = function(x, y){
  call <- match.call()
  call[[1]] <- quote(plot)
  eval.parent(call)
}
```

Comment: The top answer is very helpful. I'm trying to figure out how to modify it so that the xlab and ylab parameters are not in the parameter list but can optionally be accessed by "...". I've been trying to figure out `exists()` or `missing()` but am stuck in figuring out how to search the right environment only. Any suggestion of how to tuck these new parameters internally within the function?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you want to change. You want to hard code the clause do they can never be overridden? You can just move them out of the argument list into the body of the function, though that makes the function far less flexible. It’s very difficult to mix default clause with ... of the values aren’t in the formal argument list.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful to know. Thanks!